# Chrome extension, auto refresh page. javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a beginner at Javascript. I want to write a Chrome extension that scans a page every x seconds for changes but I can't get the button to begin refreshing.

Am I over complicating refreshing the tab? All I want is to do is keep refreshing the current tab. When I have fixed this error I need to add code that will scrape a section of the page every refresh until it finds a URL.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var beginSearchButton = document.getElementById('beginSearchButton');

      setInterval(function () {

          beginSearchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
              chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
              chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: tabs[0].url});
          });
      }); // <-- it was here

    }, 3000); // <-- should be here

}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Foley</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/popup.js">

  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ppEmail">PP Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="pp-email" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ppPassword">PP PW</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pp-password" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="searchTerm">Search Term</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="term" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <button id="beginSearchButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Begin</button>
  </form>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Foley",
  "description": "Foley",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "webNavigation",
   "*://*/*"
   ]

}
```

Comment: Your second `setInterval` param is `false`...

Comment: @PredatorIWD What should it be?

Comment: @PaulSeal, It is should be `3000`, but it is `false`. You messed with parentheses.

Comment: @Deliaz Can you show me exactly where I should put it or how it should be written? I'm very new to this. ty for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noticed in the comments, you confused with parentheses. 
Here is the correct code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var beginSearchButton = document.getElementById('beginSearch');

    setInterval(function () {

        beginSearchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: tabs[0].url});
            });
        }); // <-- it was here

    }, 3000); // <-- should be here

}, false);
```